# UUID library for C?

Tags: c, linux, uuid, pkg-config

I'm looking for a UUID library for programming in C, that has a reasonable probability of being installed (or at least installable by package manager) on most modern Linux desktops, and works with `pkg-config`.

The following two possibilities seem most obvious:

- [OSSP UUID](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/)
- Libuuid from [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/)

Does anybody have experience with these two and can recommend one over the other, or a third possiblity?

Comment: Such questions like this are today ontopic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or maybe on https://unix.stackexchange.com (the sites did not exist as the question was posted).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I used both, and I definitely prefer the util-linux-ng (formerly in e2fsprogs) one. For portability, I make my software support both and use autoconf/cmake macros to detect which one is installed.

The main problem with OSSP for me is that it abuses object-orientation in C for no good reason. An UUID is just a 128-bit number, which can be represented with a char[16] array. The UUID is usually associated with another structure (the UUID serves as a key or an identifier for such structure), so it should be good if you could inline that array in the structure itself.

With OSSP UUID, it gives you a `uuid_t*` pointer to a dynamically allocated object, which holds more state than just the UUID value. If you work with tens of thousands of objects, this sensibly makes the program slower, uses more memory and causes more memory fragmentation. In the end, to make OSSP UUID usable, you have to use it just to generate the UUID (which involves 4 calls: uuid_create, uuid_make, uuid_export and uuid_destroy) and work with the UUID value yourself. With util-linux-ng, it is just a single call: uuid_generate.

Comment: Juliano, would you mind sharing the specific Autoconf configuration directives you're using for this setup? I'm figuring it out from scratch at the moment, but being an Autotools newbie I'd feel better relying on something that's already being successfully used out in the wild. Any hints appreciated...

Comment: You can also pass in the array in OOP.