# Which UUID library to use

Tags: linux, uri, uuid, gnome

I'm writing a GUI application using GNOME technologies, and I need to define UUIDs for resources in RDF files.

I'm writing in C++ but I don't mind using a C library and wrap it in my own C++ wrapper. I also prefer to use existing common libraries than add dependencies on 3rd party libraries.

I found two libraries which seem to be standard, libuuid (which comes with the Linux kernel as  part of util-linux) and the OSSP uuid library, which has a C++ binding.

No program on my system uses OSSP uuid library, but my whole desktop depends on the libuuid package, probably because the kernel itself depends on it.

The question is, which one should I use? Is there a difference or I can just choose randomly? I don't know why there are different implementations, but I'd like to choose one and stick with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UUID library for C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566964/uuid-library-for-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Linux anyway, probably your best option is using `libuuid`. I mean, everyone is using it and it's a really nice library.

You'll have to depend on the chosen library and, most likely, `libuuid` will be already present on your user's system. You noted that no program on your system uses `OSSP`, the same is true for all my systems. So why bother and use some …let's call it *third party* library… when you already have a popular library used by everyone else and known to work very well (I don't mean that `OSSP` works worse, it's also quite good)?

I'm not aware of any reason to prefer `OSSP uuid` over `libuuid`.

*Well, I should probably note that you can simply read UUIDs from `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` but that's not as much fun as using a C library, right?.*

Comment: I read libuuid is not easily portable, so I'll have problems with kernels which aren't Linux...

Comment: @fr33domlover As far as I know that's correct and OSSP is more popular  in the FreeBSD world.

Answer (score 0):

go for libuuid, it has wider use, and it's easier to have feedback and to find docs in case of problems.