# How to generate name of non-existent file and block its creation?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I want to test "No such file" behavior in my program. To do this (for sure) I need some file name, that will point to non-existent file.

What is a method to generate such file name and guarantee its non-existense til the test finishes? - I don't have any ideas, so I've tried actually nothing.

I want to implement it in C++, but, really, it's not a C++-specific question.

---

### Update #1

It's acceptable to find solution at least for Linux.

Comment: Classic XY problem. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EJP I'm trying to check, that my program will generate certain error in case, if the required file doesn't exist.

Comment: Delete it, then run the method in question.

Comment: If you just want to test for non-existance of a file, and never actually create that file, then why not hard-code to a path and file that your system will never create automatically? Then it doesn't really matter how many processes you run in parallel.

Comment: @EJP How can I be sure, that no one else would re-create this file again - between deletion and the invocation of my method?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But what that file can be? How can I restrict it from being created by others?

Comment: Do your application or test framework run in a specific path that is unique to that application/test framework? Then just search for a `no_such_file_should_ever_exist_here` in that path. Yes, someone may manually create that file, but probably not your application/test framework unless told to specifically do so (which you will never do).

Comment: What testing framework do you use? My suggestion would be to have some service that handles IO for which you can fake the behavior. That way, you will not be dependent on the actual file system. Then, all the objects in your project that uses IO use this service as a layer.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably no way of getting a 100% guarantee, but you can
easily protect against anything created by another user, by
first creating a directory in which only you have access rights,
and then creating the file there.  After that, it's up to you to
ensure that you don't do anything you don't want.  (As a general
rule, anytime you need temporary files, creating a directory
belonging to you, and to which only you have access, is a good
precautionary move.)

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but there is always a 'root', that may change permissions, remove my precious folder or simply create file there... But I think it's better, than rely on probability of file name generators.

Comment: @abyss.7 The role of root requires it to be able to contradict your assumptions.  It can also terminate your process without cause, or even (at least under Unix) cause it to appear to have a segment violation.  There's nothing you can do, in principle, to stop root from messing with you.  (The Windows protection mechanism is somewhat more complex than that of Unix, but in the end, there must be an administrator who can do anything as well, since it is necessary in order to be able to fix things other users may have messed up.)

Comment: @abyss.7 With regards to the probability of file name generators: it's usually sufficient _if_ you use the name to create a directory, and not a file.  (If you're only using Unix, you might be interested in `mkdtemp`, which creates a new directory with a unique name.)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows use [`_tempnam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355.aspx), on POSIX (e.g. Linux or OSX) use [`tempnam`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tempnam.html).

Comment: Quote from your link: "Between the time a pathname is created and the file is opened, it is possible for some other process to create a file with the same name."

Comment: @abyss.7 Yes, and that's why it's be marked as obsolescent in favor of functions that create actual files instead. However, if you use a special directory that you know no (or very few) programs will add tiles to (that is, not the system temporary directory) then it's highly unlikely that you will have that problem.

Comment: It's a probabilistic solution, which is almost unacceptable in situations, when the tests are run on build-farms - where the temporary files and folders are created very often. Until I'm sure that all of the programs uses the same file name generator and I know its internals - to be sure in its statistical properties - I can't use any of them.

Comment: @abyss.7 In that case you have to make up your own. Maybe using an UUID? (See e.g. [here for linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566964/uuid-library-for-c))

Comment: Traditionally, `tmpnam` (the _standard_ function) mangles the process id into the name.  If so, using it to create a directory should not cause problems (but if worse comes to worse, you can loop until it works).  Alternatively, it's not very difficult to write your own, mangling in the PID, or even some random text, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is impossible to create a file name which will not exist (race conditions). You can get a name with the stdio function 'char *tmpnam(char *s);' which generate a name that are difficult to guess.

You can make up a stream to avoid the unlikely case the name will be guessed:

```
class NoFStream : public std::fstream
{
    public:
    NoFStream(const char*, ios_base::openmode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) {
        setstate(ios_base::failbit);
    }

    void open(const char*, ios_base::openmode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) {
        setstate(ios_base::failbit);
    }
};

int main()
{
    NoFStream f("/tmp/file");
    if(f >> std::ws) std::cout << "This will not succeed" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Ok - it fails" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```